# Exiting / aborting a JMeter Sampler request/ User session (on purpose) before it receives the response

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Currently there are inactive, long running queries in the DB due to the user exiting the application abruptly before receiving the response.

I would like to recreate this using JMeter by killing the sessions or aborting the thread before the sampler request receives a response

Comment: Do you use HTTP Sampler or JDBC Sampler?

Comment: @user7294900: I am using HTTP sampler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to wait for response when using HTTP Request,

You can put minimum value, as 1, in [Response Timeout](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) parameter:

> Response Timeout. Number of milliseconds to wait for a response. Note that this applies to each wait for a response. If the server response is sent in several chunks, the overall elapsed time may be longer than the timeout.